# ngInclude fails in PhoneGap build for Android

Tags: angularjs, phonegap-build

I'm using Angular and PhoneGap Build and am having a problem which only occurs when the app is built by PGB and side-loaded onto my Android mobile phone.

It works when using the emulator (in Visual Studio 2015) and via PhoneGap Desktop (`phonegap serve`).

All other Angular stuff works, but the templates don't load. `A` or `B` shows as expected, so it's not the `ngShow` stuff.

I've switched to using manual bootstrapping, but this hasn't helped.

Any suggestions anyone?

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="PageController as page">
    <header class="app-header">
        <div data-ng-show="!loggedIn">A<div data-ng-include="'views/_header/pre-login.html'"></div></div>
        <div data-ng-show="loggedIn">B<div data-ng-include="'views/_header/logged-in.html'"></div></div>
    </header>
    <div class="content" data-ng-view>
    </div>
    <footer class="app-footer" data-ng-show="loggedIn">
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pg-app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ng-app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        pgApp.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`pg-app.js`:

```
var pgApp = {
    initialize: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['fGApp'], { strictDi: false });
    }
};
```

`ng-app.js`:

```
var fGApp = angular.module('fGApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'fGControllers']);

fGApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'views/Account/_Account.html'
        })
        .when('/:controller/', {
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            templateUrl: function (path) { return 'views/' + path.controller + '/_' + path.controller + '.html'; }
        })
        .when('/:controller/:view/', {
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            templateUrl: function (path) { return 'views/' + path.controller + '/' + path.view + '.html'; }
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

fGApp.run(function ($rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;

    $route.reload();
});

var fGControllers = angular.module('fGControllers', []);

// concat'd separate files follow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming the directory `_header` to `header` (and updating the template urls) seemed to fix the error for me... probably an android webview or cordova quirk.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a bizarre quirk.

Comment: Bingo - thanks guys. Gotta love those 'undocumented features' :-)

Comment: After a bit more testing this seems to be an angularjs issue, as loading standard js files and XHRs in a directory named `_js` don't seem to exhibit the problem ...